# Progressive web app Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

Flutter default provide the PWA service to install website as a Light app.

I want to install my Website as a app.For this It requires a http server so i upload it on github. After uploading on github i getting the url for my website.Open the website in the chrome

**1.The website is taking much time to load.**

**2.I am getting error in console Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.**

I am also created a fresh project and upload on github for http server access.In the fresh project i am getting same error and taking time to load.

Please suggest me what i missing or Anything extra configuration required for PWA.

Comment: "For this It requires a http server." PWAs require an https server. Are you actually using http or is that a typo?

Comment: I am using github for http serrver. @StormyKnight

Comment: I haven't used GitHub much so I don't know off the top of my head what it is. As I said, PWAs MUST be served using HTTPS.

Comment: GitHub also provide the http server for the web. @StormyKnight

Comment: @StormyKnight GitHub uses https.

Comment: I have similar issue but only with Safari and Orion. Chrome and Firefox start service worker.